# Cell to Equal Value of Different Cell based on Match in Array

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Need to Column C to equal the text in Column G based on the match the value in Column B.

I do have Column C matching the row in which the value is found (based on columns B and F)

`Column C's Formula =MATCH(B1,$F$1:$F$39,0)`

In the first row, you'll see that I found the row its corresponding value row is in. In CELL C1 for example, I would want to see `112-Campaign Access`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that I should have looked into this a bit more before begging for an answer. I'll keep the question here as it does provide some good info.

Using the function `lookup`, I was able to select the value in Column B and reference it to Column F and return the value in Column G

`=LOOKUP(B1,$F$1:$F$39,$G$1:$G$39)`

Answer (score 2):

LOOKUP is fine as long as B1 exists in F1:F39 (and because F1:F39 is sorted ascending), but what if B1 is 120? Your formula will return `113-Campaign Implementation`. If you want `#N/A` in that case (as you would get with your MATCH function) then better to use `VLOOKUP`, i.e.

`=VLOOKUP(B1,$F$1:$G$39,2,FALSE)`

...or you can use INDEX with your MATCH, i.e.

`=INDEX($G$1:$G$39,MATCH(B1,$F$1:$F$39,0))`